# Is there any program (or code, any language) that will mute all of the microphones on my computer?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microphone, hotkeys, c#, mute

Is there any program (or code, any language) that will mute all of the microphones on my computer? If it is code, please make it as simple as possible, the only language I know is C# and I am still VERY new to it. I just want to setup some way to mute my microphones from a hotkey/shortcut, and if I can just find a program that can do, I will be set. As I said, I can also do a little bit if it is in C#, but the only code I have seen before for this, was miles long (atleast to me). My goal, is I just want a program that opens up, and toggles the mute on the microhpones (all of the system audio input) then closes. That is it, very simple. Thank you to anyone who trys to helps me!

EDIT:
Yes, I am using Windows. I am using Windows 7 32-bit. I already know that I can go into the volume mixer and do it that way, but I need to do this while running a full screen application, and it is a hassle to have to exit fullscreen, open the volume mixer, the click the mute icon, then go back into full screen and the the whole thing over again to unmute it. And I will be toggling back and forth quite often, so it just takes alot to do that so much.

Comment: I'm not sure what code there might be, but can you not simply access the microphone's controls? You don't specify your platform -so I'm assuming Windows (though I'm making no guesses as to which version)- the control panel should allow control of this nature. (Also: voting to close as it seems closer to the remit of www.superuser.com than stackoverflow.)

Comment: There's an article at codeguru with csharp control of audio devices -  http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/sound/article.php/c10931/ if anyone wants to take a crack at it, this would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) would probably do the trick.  It has a "[SoundSet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm)" command that can adjust volume/mute levels for all audio devices.

EDIT:

Here's [someone's AHK script doing exactly](http://www.tacticalgamer.com/battlefield-2142-technical-support-faqs/140607-something-might-useful-fraps-microphone-users.html) what you're looking for.

Comment: That might be able to work, but unless I missed something simple, that still seemed a mile long, and I want to mute just the microhpone, but keep the rest of the sound running fine.

Comment: There's a "ComponentType" parameter which can be used to specify just the microphone.